# Send a text message for a specific number using WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android, whatsapp

I'm trying to open WhatsApp with both text message and phone number, the phone number is OK but the **message are not being displayed**

Here's my code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    sendIntent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
                    sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
                    sendIntent.PutExtra("jid", phone_number + "@s.whatsapp.net");
                    sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "extra_text test");
                    sendIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", "sms_body test");
                    sendIntent.PutExtra("body", "body test");
                    sendIntent.PutExtra("text", "text test");
                    context.StartActivity(sendIntent);
```

I've tried all these "PutExtra" options but it's not working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What they allow via Intent extras is limited.

#### C# Example:

```
var sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "StackOverflow.");
sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
StartActivity(sendIntent);
```

Ref: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

Comment: **Thanks** for the help, but I can either get the number or the message, not both.

Comment: @mrelva Using the `jid` to set the number via an extra is a hack and was obtained via reverse engineering the WhatApp apk, it is just not supported... the only thing "officially" supported is setting the message and/or auto-attaching media files....